# Just installed phpmyadmin. Unicode is not working

Tags: mysql, unicode, phpmyadmin

I tried changing the collation of the field to utf8_unicode_ci, but it didn't work.
If you just installed phpmyadmin for a non-english (unicode) website, how would you set the encoding?

Comment: `utf8_unicode_ci` has nothing to do with encoding. Describe your issue more detailed.

Comment: I need to store Unicode characters. :)

Comment: @Da9: then create your tables with `utf8` charset. PMA's settings don't affect on schema.

Comment: Thanks. If I already have a table, is there a way to convert it instead of creating a new one?

Comment: @Da9: it depends on many cases. As I said - give more details in the question: the script that created table, what kind of data in the table and in which encoding, etc.

Comment: have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138697/convert-mysql-latin1-swedish-ci-to-utf8-bin/5494846#5494846