# Convert Mysql latin1_swedish_ci to utf8_bin

Tags: mysql, collation

I want to know how to convert *MySql latin1_swedish_ci*(eg.所 有 重) to *utf8_bin*(所 有 重) using SQL or command line. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 5):

You may try this

Convert existing MySQL **database** from one charset encoding to another

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Convert **existing table** from one charset encoding to another

```
ALTER TABLE db_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Hope this help.

Nathanphan